# How to Apply Pricing Template to a Newly Created Subscription in Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

Following the recent updates to Google Play Console, the process of creating a subscription now requires the creation of a base plan. However, the method for applying prices using the pricing template is not readily apparent. What should I do to apply the proces from the template to the base plan?

I looked into the Documentation and don't see a way to apply prices in Subscriptions via templates anymore.

Comment: Yea it looks like they removed this ability so you have to do it manually every time you change the price. Have you found a way to do it? Even worse, subscriptions now have more countries to set prices for then in-app products.